# How to get a value from a website using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The website in question is thingspeak. I'm trying to get the temperature of my room using amazon alexa. I send the data to thingspeak and the website displays this `{"created_at":"2019-03-09T05:21:52Z","entry_id":185,"field1":"21.00"}` I want to get the value form the website, the 21.00. This is the code I have:

```
    var channel_id = 123456;
    var speak_key = 'ABCD2456ABCD2456';
    var url = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel_id + '/feed/last.json?api_key=' + speak_key;
    const MyRoomHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
          || (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && request.intent.name === 'MyRoomIntent');  
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        const lastTemp;         
        const speechOutput = GET_MESSAGE + lastTemp + TEMP_DEGREES;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechOutput)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };
const SKILL_NAME = 'My Room';
const GET_MESSAGE = 'The temperature is ';
const TEMP_DEGREES = ' Degrees Celsius.';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me to get the temperature, or you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';
```

I just don't know how to have the variable lastTemp get that value, the 21.00 from the website. I don't know javascript. I'm gonna start learning it now for future projects, just need to figure this part out. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is a modern alternative, it's easier to use than XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess it's just all too advanced for me. I been reading online on both of those suggestions and just can't figure it out. I'm gonna just have to start from the beggining. Thank you both.